# Daemon Service looses database connection after serving around 5 requests

Tags: ruby

I am using a default ruby daemon service and it serves the first 5 request(requests which fires a query to database) after which it fails to connect to database.

I am using Active Record to connect MySQL database and EM HTTP server. I have another daemon service which are running successful using same tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the number of pool connections you are using and see to it that you are releasing it after use.

Generally it is set at 5.

You can release a connection by using the following code:

`ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.checkin(ActiveRecord::Base.connection)`

Where `ActiveRecord::Base.connection` holds the connection details obtained from the database configuration details.